# Collatz Sequence - printing every sequence from 1 until N

Tags: java, sequence, collatz

I have this HW assignment that I'm stuck in:
I need to write the sequence from 1 until N given seed.
for example:
if user inputs 4 v then I need to write every line from the first sequence until the 4th and then write down how many have reached 1 in the end and count the number of numbers.
example:

```
   1 4 2 1 (4)
   2 1 (2)
   3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 (8)
   4 2 1 (3)
s.o.p :The first 4 hailstone sequences reached 1.
```

if user inputs 7 c then I only need to write the sentence The first 4 hailstone sequences reached 1.

so far I've written the code for the v part,
the part that works:
    public class Collatz {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String str = String.valueOf(args[1]);
    int counter = 1;
    if (str.equals("v")) {
        while (n != 1) 
    { 
        System.out.print(n + " "); 

        // If n is odd 
        if ((n & 1) == 1) {
            n = 3 * n + 1; 
        }
        // If even 
        else{
            n = n / 2; 
        }
        counter++;

    } 

    // Print 1 at the end 

    System.out.print(n + " (" + counter + ")");

    }
}
```

}

I have tried putting a for loop to print from 1 to n in order to print like my example but it doesn't, my attempt:

```
 `          for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i+1){
        while (i!= 1) {
          System.out.print(i + " "); 

        // If n is odd 
        if ((i & 1) == 1) 
            i = 3 * i + 1; 

        // If even 
        else
            i = i / 2; 
    } 

    // Print 1 at the end 
    System.out.print(i); `
```

no go. please help me debug this.

Comment: What's the problem? That's not clear. And your use of `&` seems odd. I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be a `%`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `(n & 1) == 1` is a fast oddness test for integers using bitwise arithmetic (avoiding costly division)

Comment: @GyroGearless Ahh, new one for me. I've always just used modulo. Never had to use it in a performance sensitive context before.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:
add: before the while

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i+1){
                hail = i;       // we need to make sure i isn't run over            
                int counter = 1;
```